# Calling http handler in user control

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, postback

I'm trying to call httphandler in SharePoint usercontrol.

I'm loading this usercontrol in a SharePoint web part. This httphandler is deployed to SharePoint layouts folder.

Below is my code .

```
this.Page.Form.Action = "/_layouts/handler/FileHandler.ashx";  

this.Page.Form.Method = "POST";
this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
```

On page load or button click event , my handler is called but context.Request.HttpMethod is always "GET" instead of "POST .

It works fine in Chrome but it is very inconsistent. Both in Internet Explorer and Chrome, it is always get method. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.